# XCode Archive error in prefix header

Tags: ios, xcode5, archive, gpuimage, prefix

I'm using **GPUImage** framework in my project and this is added to the projects target dependencies. This actually builds and runs fine. Problem occurred when i tried to archive the project for ipa file. the error shows 'could not build module 'Foundation' -inside the **GPUImage-Prefix.pch**.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Is it conflicting with import of the project's ProjectName-Prefix.pch ?

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

I am keen to know how to solve this with ideal practice. I did weak-link the Core Video framework in my project settings as per the [GPUImage guideline](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-the-static-library-to-your-ios-project), but no use at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can  delete   /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache  then clean the project

Comment: another direct effective method is uninstall Xcode  and  install it again

Answer (score 0):

I did next: `pod deintegrate` then removed anything that found for cocoapods and for broken module. Also i did renamed a target and removed unused schemes. Cleaned project and build folder.
After this i did `pod install`. Opened the new .xcworkspace (new because changed name of the target). Thats worked for me.